# How can I fix my code that returns 'undefined' at two specific arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, slice

I am begginer at JavaScript and currently training at Code Wars, and I have some problems with my code here. I got a task to find a number in a given array, that differs from the other numbers in the same array. When I run the tests only at those two specific arrays the code returns 'undefined'. So I wanted to know why and how should I improve my code? Maybe I missed something.
Appreciate your help.

Here is my code:

```
function findUniq(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== arr[0]  && arr[i] !== arr.slice(-1)[0]) {
      return arr[i]; 
    } 
  }
}
```

So I have those two arrays:

`findUniq([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]);` expected `0`, but returns `undefined`.

`findUniq([8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7]);` expected `7`, also returns `undefined`.

Comment: Can you please give **codewars** problem link?

Comment: This code is finding the first value that equals neither the first nor the last value.  In those two arrays there is nothing that matches that criteria.  If you want to find the value that equals none of the others, you will need to do something more.

Comment: So I tried the OR operator it is making progress now everything is working except the second given array it returns 8 and not 7.

Comment: @JonasWilms: how would that help?

Comment: @scott it would at least solve one of the two testcases :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use reduce to club digits as key-value pair and than find the key which has value 1

```js
function findUniq(input){
  let op = input.reduce((op,inp)=>{
    if(op[inp]){
      op[inp]++;
    } else {
      op[inp] = 1
    }
    return op
  },{})
  return Object.keys(op).find(e=> op[e] === 1)
}

console.log(findUniq([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]))
console.log(findUniq([8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7]))
```

Answer (score 0):

For every element in the array you check wether it unequals the first *and* the last position:

```
 //❌                    ✔️
 //                    
   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 //⬆️
```

Now for the first element (which is the one to find), comparing to the last element will result in "unequal", because 0 is not 1, but checking for the first will result in "equal" as you compare the elementto itself.

---

For it to detect the first and last element, don't check if it unequals both the first and the last, but wether it unequals the previous and the next, then jump back to the end or beginning when the index leaves the array.

Through that it also works for the last and the first element:

```
 //   ✔️                 ✔️
 //                    
   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
 //⬆️
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way is, as Jonas Wilms suggested, to find the first one that is not equal to both its predecessor and its successor, wrapping around at the end of the list:

```js
const findUnique = arr => arr.find((n, i, a) => 
  n !== a[(i - 1) % arr.length] && n !== a[(i + 1 % arr.length)]
)

console.log(findUnique([1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])) //~> 3
console.log(findUnique([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])) //~> 0
console.log(findUnique([8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 7])) //~> 7
```

Note that this uses `%`, the [remainder or modulus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) operator of Javascript to handle sliding off the end of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function findUniq(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== arr[arr.length - (i-1)] && arr[i] !== arr[arr.length + (i-1)] && arr[i] !== arr[i+1] && arr[i] !== arr[i-1]) {
     return arr[i]; 
    } 
  }
}
```

Well here is my own answer thanks to everyone, I will take to attention any critics you have, to improve.Thanks to Jonas Wilms:)